# Django rest framework serializer validation error messages in array

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is there a way to get array of error messages instead of object when retrieving validation errors from serializers?

For example:

```
[
        "User with this email already exists.",
        "User with this phone number already exists."
]
```

Instead of:

```
{
        "email": [
            "User with this email already exists."
        ],
        "phone_number": [
            "User with this phone number already exists."
        ]
}
```

Comment: afaik, no way to do that, because it how DRF implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle the exceptions in any serializer of your application in the way you mentioned, you can write your own custom exception handler under your application directory (e.g. `my_project/my_app/custom_exception_handler`):

```py
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    """ Call REST framework's default exception handler first, to get the standard error response.
    """
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response is not None:
        # Place here your code
        errors = response.data
        ...

        # return the `response.data`
        # response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code
    return response
```

After that update the `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` value in your `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Checkout more details in the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)

Comment: How can I return only a single message? Suppose my serializer returns 3 errors as arrays. I need to send only one, as a string, not an array. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, you have to check if serializer is not valid, then using for loop iterate key of error_dict and append value in list and return list

```
serializer = YourSerializer(data={"email":"abc@gmail.com", "phone_number": "1234566"})
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
else:
    error_list = [serializer.errors[error][0] for error in serializer.errors]
    return Response(error_list)
```